# How to remove clogging in aircraft fuel nozzles?

Tags: jet-engine, aircraft-maintenance

I have a dual orfice fuel nozzle (Used in CFM56 Engine/ Parker make). The secondary orifice is not opening up even at the required injection pressure. It had been not used for 3 years and I assume that it is clogged. Please suggest a method to clean this.

Comment: Is that [the part you are talking about](http://i.stack.imgur.com/AtRA9.jpg)? What is the context of your question... are you doing engine maintenance or using the nozzle for another purpose not related to aviation?

Comment: @mins Thanks for your response. This is exactly the nozzle which I am using. I am a graduate student and I am using this nozzle along with swirl cup to study gas turbine engine sprays. I had a total of two nozzles, and  tested another one also. Here only secondary orifice is opening , not the primary one, which is opposite to the previous case.  kerosene is used as the test fluid.  Is this because of some rusting or clogging in cartridge valve assembly ?  I am not sure how to solve this, please help.

Answer (score 4):

[Hoppes No. 9](http://www.hoppes.com/bore-cleaners/no-9-solvent) is often used for cleaning aircraft fuel injection nozzles in general. This solvent is widely available for cleaning firearms. The cleaning procedure typically involves submerging the detached nozzles in the solvent for as long as necessary, typically 10-60 minutes depending on the level of fouling.

Disclaimer: I don't have any specific maintenance data on your nozzles, so you may want be wary of the applicability of the information I offer.